# How to create a color-overlay on an image?

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have an accordion with images in each panel. I want to have a blue overlay on top of each image. How can I accomplish this?

The last part of the CSS `.panel-img` is where it would go (I think)

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/SnowboardBruin/pen/WPWLzj)

```
 <div class="slider-containers">
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="flexbox-slider flexbox-slider-1">
    <div class="flexbox-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1464213/pexels-photo-1464213.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image" class="panel-img">
      <div class="start">Engage</div>
      <div class="text-block">
        <h3>Engage</h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1350615/pexels-photo-1350615.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image"  class="panel-img">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h3>Educate</h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1093913/pexels-photo-1093913.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image" class="panel-img">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h3>Empower</h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//variables
$slider-height: 500px;
$text-block-width: 400px;

$dark-font-color: #212121;
$accent-font-color: #CA9CE1;
$light-font-color: #fff;
$text-overlay-color: #000;
$text-overlay-opacity: 0.6;
$slide-overlay-color: #fff;
$slide-overlay-opacity: 0.6;

//transitions and mixins

//transitions mixin
@mixin transition-mix($property: all, $duration: 0.2s, $timing: linear, $delay: 0s) {
  transition-property: $property;
  transition-duration: $duration;
  transition-timing-function: $timing;
  transition-delay: $delay;
}

//position absolute mixin
@mixin position-absolute ($top: null, $left: null, $right: null, $bottom: null) {
  position: absolute;
  top: $top;
  left: $left;
  right: $right;
  bottom: $bottom;
}

/*common styles !!!YOU DON'T NEED THEM */


.container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;


}

  .link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;

    a {
      @include transition-mix;

      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      margin-right: 40px;
      color: inherit;
      font: {
        size: inherit;
      }
      text-decoration: none;

      &:hover {
        color: $accent-font-color;
      }

      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }

      i {
        color: $accent-font-color;
        margin-right: 9px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
  }

.slider-containers {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 60px  ;
}

.slider-container {
  margin-bottom: 60px;

  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.flexbox-slider {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/*slide styles !!!YOU NEED THEM */
.flexbox-slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: $slider-height;
  visibility: hidden;

  .flexbox-slide {
    @include transition-mix($duration: .3s);

    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: skewx(-8deg);

    //overlay
    &:after {
      @include position-absolute($top: 0, $left: 0);
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba($slide-overlay-color, $slide-overlay-opacity);
      z-index: 2;

      opacity: 0;
    }

    img {
      @include position-absolute($top: 50%, $left: 50%);
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .text-block {
      @include position-absolute($bottom: 30px, $left: 30px);
      max-width: $text-block-width;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: rgba($text-overlay-color, $text-overlay-opacity);
      color: $light-font-color;

      z-index: 4;

      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;

      h3 {
        font: {
          size: 20px;
          weight: 700;
        }
      }
    }
  }

    &:hover {

    .flexbox-slide:hover {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
}

/* effect  */
.flexbox-slider.flexbox-slider-1 {

  .flexbox-slide {

    .text-block {
      bottom: 60px;
    }
  }

  &:hover {

    .start {visibility:hidden}

    .flexbox-slide:hover {

      .text-block {
        @include transition-mix($delay: .5s);
        bottom: 30px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
  }
}
.start {font-weight: bold; color: black; font-size: 150%; z-index:1000; margin: 50px; 
}
.start:hover {color: green}
.panel-img {backgroud-color: rgba(0,0,255,.8)}
img.panel-img {height:500px !important; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the image tab with a div tag and set the background color with the rgba code for blue [ex. rgba(34, 167, 240, .5)] Set the opacity of the color by changing the last value of the rgba.

```
<div class="img-overlay">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1093913/pexels-photo-1093913.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image" class="panel-img">
</div>


.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(34, 167, 240, .5);
}
```